# Validar campo para aceitar números inteiro e decimais

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

Como fazer com JavaScript, para que um `input` tipo texto aceite apenas números inteiros e números decimais com até 2 casas decimais.

Ex:

```
1    - true
1,1  - true
1,11 - true


$("body").on("input", ".number", function(event){
    $(this).val(this.value.replace(/\D/g, ''));
})
```

Answer (score 5):

Você pode usar a propriedade [`pattern`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/text#pattern), que define o formato que o campo pode ter, usando uma expressão regular para tal:

```css
/* deixa uma borda vermelha enquanto o campo estiver inválido */
input:invalid {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<form>
<input type="text" pattern="^\d+(,\d{1,2})?$" required>
</form>
```

Explicando a regex:

`\d+` é "um ou mais dígitos".

Em seguida, temos um trecho entre parênteses: uma vírgula seguida de `\d{1,2}` (um ou dois dígitos). E o `?` depois dos parênteses torna todo este trecho [opcional](https://www.regular-expressions.info/optional.html).

Ou seja, podemos ter vários dígitos, ou vários dígitos seguido de vírgula, seguido de um ou dois dígitos.

Além disso, a regex tem os [marcadores](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) `^` e `$`, que são respectivamente o início e fim da string. Assim, eu garanto que o campo só terá o que está especificado na regex.

---

O que o seu `replace(/\D/g, '')` está fazendo é substituir todos os `\D` (ou seja, qualquer caractere que **não** seja dígito) por `''` (a string vazia). Ou seja, você está removendo tudo que não é um dígito do valor do campo (se o valor for, por exemplo, `abc123!@#,:.x`, o resultado do `replace` será `123` -  tudo que não é dígito é removido). Por isso ele não funciona para validar o formato do campo.

Answer (score 0):

```css
input { box-sizing: border-box; width: 100%; border: 1px solid; outline: none; }
:valid { border-color: green; }
:invalid { border-color: red; }
```

```html
<input pattern="\d+,?\d{0,2}" autofocus>
```